# Black screen appears when I select Ubuntu at the boot screen

Tags: grub2, startup

I tried to install ubuntu 12.10 but the installation didn't complete. It got stuck at the last moment and my PC restarted after that. Now it shows four options. Advance menu for Ubuntu, Ubuntu and two others for memory test. When I try to start Ubuntu, nothing happens. There only appears a black screen where I can type in to.

Comment: How did you run the initial install?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall, completing the installation. You will spend less time reinstalling Ubuntu and completing the installation, rather than troubleshoot what is going wrong with your botched install.

Comment: How can i re install??? Boot screen doesnt appear.i have ubuntu loaded as os.but how xan i reinstall...???

Comment: I suggest doing what you did to install it the first time, again. Did you boot a disk with install .iso burned? If so, boot that disk again. Did you boot from a unetbootin USB drive? However you installed it the first time, do that again